# Template Render Shortcuts not showing any result

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, pymongo

I am trying to pass a variable from pymongo on my views.py to a template. I am not getting any errors but neither is my code being rendered to my template.

views.py:

```
    def getTheA(request):
       for x in mycol.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$tags"},{'$match': {'tags.tag.name':'A A',}},{'$project': {'url': 1, 'AR': 1, 'tags.tag.name': 1, 'tags.variables': 1, '_id': 0}},]):
           theURLs = x['url']
           theNames = json.dumps(x['tags']['tag']['name'])
           theVars = json.dumps(x['tags']['variables'])
           context = {'theURLs' : theURLs}
       return render(request, 'templates/a.html', context)
```

My HTML code is pretty simple. I am just trying to print a list of the urls:

```
   <ul>
      <li><b>URLSSSS</h1></b>
      {% for theURL in theURLs %}
         <li>{{ theURL.theURLs }} </li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

My result:

- **URLSSSS**

I am new to Django and MongoDb and can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: You should use *double* curly brackets, so `{{ theURL.theURLs }}`.

Comment: Furthermore the `for` loop is rather strange: it will take the last (?!) element as values for `theURLs`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I do have double curly brackets in my code. I forgot to add that here. I have made the change

Comment: @newbierp can you tell me what theURL.theURLs should be giving you?  I have a feeling that the reason you are not getting any output is because that is incorrect.  Also, can you do a full inspect of the html and make sure that there is not a bunch of empty <li> elements after your initial one?

Comment: My inspect doesn't show the empty <li>'s. `x['url']` just contains a a list of urls like so: www.google.com www.bing.com

Answer (score 0):

When you have `{{ x.y }}` in a template, that means "attribute or dictionary key `y` of object `x`".

So, in your template, when you have `{{ theURL.theURLs }}`, that means "attribute or dictionary key `theURLs` of object `theURL`.

`theURL` is already looping over each object in `theURLs`.  Do those objects really have attributes also named `theURLs`?  Nothing in your code suggests this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after looking at your code for a long time, there are two main problems.

1. `<li>{{ theURL.theURLs }}</li>` should just be `<li>{{ theURL }}</li>`
2. Your for loop is seriously messed up.  In its current form, you only take the last URL that you iterate over.  Fix it in this way:

   `def getTheA(request):
       theURLs = []
       for yadayadayada:
           theURLs.append(x['url'])
           theNames = json.dumps(x['tags']['tag']['name'])
           theVars = json.dumps(x['tags']['variables'])
       context = { 'theURLs' : theURLs }
       return render(request, 'templates/a.html', context=context)`

Comment: Shouldn't the `theURLs.append(x['url'])` be equal to another variable?

Comment: no. You want to define `theURLs` as a list, and for each item in your for loop, you want to append that url to the list.

Comment: this is my HTML code: <ul>
  <li><h1>URLSSSS-WHYYYY</h1></li>
  {% for theURL in theURLs %}
    <li>{{ theURLs }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul> . I am still not getting any urls

Comment: well first of all, you should be printing `theURL` instead of `theURLs` in your <li>.  But I have a feeling that your problem lays more in your understanding of python, mongo, and django in general.  I'd suggest starting with pieces of this project and making sure you understand how each piece works before joining them.  For instance, hard code a list and figure out how to print them into HTML, then figure out how to just print all of your urls to the terminal, and then combine them.

Comment: I am able to print them in terminal. I am not getting results even I change it to {{ theURL }}